# Mp4 files codec not found

Tags: php

I create a script to download video from remote host the content length of file is shows correct and download properly without any interruptions. But When playing video file it shows error **The Player might not support the file type or might not support the codec that was used to compress the file.**
Here is my php code

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
$useragent = "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux amd64; rv:21.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/21.0";

$url=($_GET['q']);
$headers = array(
    "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9",
    "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br",
    "Accept-Charset: utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3",
    "Accept-Language:en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4",
    "Connection: keep-alive",
);
$v = $url;
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 222222);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $v);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $useragent);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$info = curl_exec($ch);
$size2 = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_CONTENT_LENGTH_DOWNLOAD);
$namer= basename($v,"=m18");
header('Connection: Keep-Alive');
header('Content-Type: video/mp4; charset=');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary\n');
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
header('Content-Length: ' . $size2);
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: private');
header('Pragma: no-cache');
//header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate"); // HTTP/1.1
header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename=");

echo($v);
```

Comment: Look at the headers returned by the curl response, content-type and content-encoding in particular. Are you getting back compressed (gzip) data? If you pass it directly down to your PHP script's client with an incorrect content type, media playback won't work.

Comment: You are sending `Accept-Encoding` to permit gzip to begin with, a well configured server would probably not attempt to gzip audio/video data because they are already compressed and it would be extremely resource intensive.

Comment: How can i fix it ?

Comment: If that is the problem, I have just made a wild guess, remove your `Accept-Encoding` header.

Comment: problem is same.